# ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, proxy

**class Client:**

```
package com.sdzee.tp.beans;   
public class Client implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String  nom;
    private String  prenom;
    private String  adresse;
    private String  telephone;
    private String  email;
    private String  image;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Integer id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNom( String nom ) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setPrenom( String prenom ) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {

        return prenom;
    }

    public void setAdresse( String adresse ) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone( String telephone ) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public void setEmail( String email ) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setImage( String image )
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }
}
```

**class Commande:**

```
package com.sdzee.tp.beans;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Commande implements java.io.Serializable {
    /* Propriétés du bean */
    private Integer  id;
    private Client   client;
    private DateTime date;
    private Double   montant;
    private String   modePaiement;
    private String   statutPaiement;
    private String   modeLivraison;
    private String   statutLivraison;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Integer id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient( Client client ) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public DateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate( DateTime date ) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Double getMontant() {
        return montant;
    }

    public void setMontant( Double montant ) {
        this.montant = montant;
    }

    public String getModePaiement() {
        return modePaiement;
    }

    public void setModePaiement( String modePaiement ) {
        this.modePaiement = modePaiement;
    }

    public String getStatutPaiement() {
        return statutPaiement;
    }

    public void setStatutPaiement( String statutPaiement ) {
        this.statutPaiement = statutPaiement;
    }

    public String getModeLivraison() {
        return modeLivraison;
    }

    public void setModeLivraison( String modeLivraison ) {
        this.modeLivraison = modeLivraison;
    }

    public String getStatutLivraison() {
        return statutLivraison;
    }

    public void setStatutLivraison( String statutLivraison ) {
        this.statutLivraison = statutLivraison;
    }
}
```

**class ClientDao:**

```
package com.sdzee.tp.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.sdzee.tp.beans.Client;

public class ClientDao {
    public void creer( Client client )
    {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save( client );
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            if ( trns != null ) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public Client trouver( Integer id ) {
        Client user = null;
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            String queryString = "from Client where id = :id";
            Query query = session.createQuery( queryString );
            query.setInteger( "id", id );
            user = (Client) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return user;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public List<Client> lister() {
        List<Client> users = new ArrayList<Client>();
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try
        {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            users = session.createQuery( "from Client" ).list();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return users;
    }

    public void supprimer( Client client ) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            Client user = (Client) session.load( Client.class, new Long( client.getId() ) );
            session.delete( user );
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            if ( trns != null ) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**class CommandeDao:**

```
package com.sdzee.tp.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.sdzee.tp.beans.Client;
import com.sdzee.tp.beans.Commande;

public class CommandeDao {
    public void creer( Commande commande )
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save( commande );
            transaction.commit();
        } catch ( HibernateException e ) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public Client trouver( long id ) {
        Client user = null;
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            String queryString = "from Commande where id = :id";
            Query query = session.createQuery( queryString );
            query.setLong( "id", id );
            user = (Client) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List<Commande> lister() {
        List<Commande> users = new ArrayList<Commande>();
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            users = session.createQuery( "from Commande" ).list();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return users;
    }

    public void supprimer( Commande commande ) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            Client user = (Client) session.load( Client.class, new Integer( commande.getId() ) );
            session.delete( user );
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
            if ( trns != null ) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**class PrechargementFilter:**

```
package com.sdzee.tp.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.sdzee.tp.beans.Client;
import com.sdzee.tp.beans.Commande;
import com.sdzee.tp.dao.ClientDao;
import com.sdzee.tp.dao.CommandeDao;

public class PrechargementFilter implements Filter {
    public static final String CONF_DAO_FACTORY      =
                                                             "daofactory";
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_CLIENTS   = "clients";
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_COMMANDES =
                                                             "commandes";
    private ClientDao          clientDao;
    private CommandeDao        commandeDao;

    public void init( FilterConfig config ) throws
            ServletException {
        /*
         * Récupération d'une instance de nos DAO Client et Commande
         */

    }

    public void doFilter( ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain ) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        /* Cast de l'objet request */
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        /* Récupération de la session depuis la requête */
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        /*
         * Si la map des clients n'existe pas en session, alors l'utilisateur se
         * connecte pour la première fois et nous devons précharger en session
         * les infos contenues dans la BDD.
         */

        clientDao = new ClientDao();
        commandeDao = new CommandeDao();
        if ( session.getAttribute( ATT_SESSION_CLIENTS ) == null )
        {
            /*
             * Récupération de la liste des clients existant, et enregistrement
             * en session
             */

            List<Client> listeClients = clientDao.lister();
            Map<Integer, Client> mapClients = new HashMap<Integer,
                    Client>();
            for ( Client client : listeClients ) {
                mapClients.put( client.getId(), client );
            }
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_CLIENTS, mapClients
                    );
        }
        /*
         * De même pour la map des commandes
         */
        if ( session.getAttribute( ATT_SESSION_COMMANDES ) == null ) {
            /*
             * Récupération de la liste des commandes existant, et
             * enregistrement en session
             */
            List<Commande> listeCommandes = commandeDao.lister();
            Map<Integer, Commande> mapCommandes = new HashMap<Integer,
                    Commande>();
            for ( Commande commande : listeCommandes ) {
                mapCommandes.put( commande.getId(), commande );
            }
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_COMMANDES,
                    mapCommandes );
        }
        /* Pour terminer, poursuite de la requête en cours */

        chain.doFilter( request, res );
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

**class ListeCommandes:**

```
package com.sdzee.tp.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ListeCommandes extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long  serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String ATT_COMMANDE     = "commande";
    public static final String ATT_FORM         = "form";
    public static final String VUE              = "/WEB-INF/listerCommandes.jsp";

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        /*
         * À la réception d'une requête GET, affichage de la liste des commandes
         */
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE
                ).forward( request, response );
    }
}
```

when i try to access to listeCommandes i have this exception:

```
 ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.sdzee.tp.beans.Client_$$_javassist_0.getPrenom(Client_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDynamicExpression.getValue(AstDynamicExpression.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.listerCommandes_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(listerCommandes_jsp.java:379)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.listerCommandes_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(listerCommandes_jsp.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.listerCommandes_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f0(listerCommandes_jsp.java:267)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.listerCommandes_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(listerCommandes_jsp.java:197)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.listerCommandes_jsp._jspService(listerCommandes_jsp.java:111)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.sdzee.tp.servlets.ListeCommandes.doGet(ListeCommandes.java:26)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.sdzee.tp.filters.PrechargementFilter.doFilter(PrechargementFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

FOR ZEUS

this is the listercommande.jsp

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Liste des commandes existantes</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url
value="/inc/style.css"/>" />
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="/inc/menu.jsp" />
<div id="corps">
<c:choose>
<%-- Si aucune commande n'existe en session, affichage
d'un message par défaut. --%>
<c:when test="${ empty sessionScope.commandes }">
<p class="erreur">Aucune commande enregistrée.</p>
</c:when>
<%-- Sinon, affichage du tableau. --%>
<c:otherwise>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Client</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Montant</th>
<th>Mode de paiement</th>
<th>Statut de paiement</th>
<th>Mode de livraison</th>
<th>Statut de livraison</th>
<th class="action">Action</th>
</tr>
<%-- Parcours de la Map des commandes en session,
et utilisation de l'objet varStatus. --%>
<c:forEach items="${ sessionScope.commandes }"
var="mapCommandes" varStatus="boucle">
<%-- Simple test de parité sur l'index de
parcours, pour alterner la couleur de fond de chaque ligne du
tableau. --%>
<tr class="${boucle.index % 2 == 0 ? 'pair' :
'impair'}">
<%-- Affichage des propriétés du bean
Commande, qui est stocké en tant que valeur de l'entrée courante
de la map --%>
<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.client.prenom } ${
mapCommandes.value.client.nom }"/></td>
<td><joda:format value="${
mapCommandes.value.date }" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.montant }"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.modePaiement }"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.statutPaiement }"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.modeLivraison }"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.statutLivraison }"/></td>
<%-- Lien vers la servlet de suppression, avec
passage de la date de la commande - c'est-à-dire la clé de la Map
- en paramètre grâce à la balise <c:param/>. --%>
<td class="action">
<a href="<c:url
value="/suppressionCommande"><c:param name="idCommande" value="${
mapCommandes.key }" /></c:url>">
<img src="<c:url
value="/inc/supprimer.png"/>" alt="Supprimer" />
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try to reduce the code the minimal set triggering the bug.

Comment: What is in the ListerCommandes.jsp file? I think this file is retrieving the value that is not pulled initially from the hibernate query. If you cn post the code here for that it will help .

Comment: the listercommande.jsp in the answer i added now

Comment: i think that the problem in this lines
 

<td><c:out value="${
mapCommandes.value.client.prenom } ${
mapCommandes.value.client.nom }"/></td>

when i delete it works.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've closed the HibernateSession before retrieving all the data needed. There are a few ways to work around this. Have a look at the following link: [Hibernate LazyInitializationException while using collection in Spring JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047835/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-while-using-collection-in-spring-jsp-page/19048508#19048508)

Comment: thanks but i use hibernate with servlet only i want a way to solve this problem

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding @Proxy(lazy=false) to the problem Entity. Got the suggestion from http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/04/orghibernatelazyinitializationException-Could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-hibernate-java.html

Answer (score 0):

add lazy=false into  in your *.hbm.xml file or you can init your object in Hibernate.init(Object) when you get object from db