# LazyInitializationException when loading entity children with FetchType.LAZY

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, lazy-loading

I am getting a [`LazyInitializationException`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html) when my `JSF` view requests a list of children for an entity.  I am not using `Hibernate` directly but `JPA`. The CHILD DB table does have a FK on the PARENT table.  It is a very standard relationship.

Here is what the relevant code excerpts look like:

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Parent.getByID", 
            query = "SELECT i FROM Parent i WHERE i.parentID = :parentID")})
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="PARENT_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="DB_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PARENT_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private long parentID;

    /* other stuff */

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> childList;

    /* other stuff */

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return this.childList;
    }
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Child.getByID", 
            query = "SELECT i FROM Child i WHERE i.childID = :childID")})

public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CHILD_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="DB_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CHILD_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name="CHILD_ID")
    private long childID;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;
```

**View**

```
<h:dataTable id="childTbl" value="#{parent.children}" 
        var="child" width="100%"
        styleClass="data" border="1" cellpadding="2"
        cellspacing="0">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Child Name</f:facet>
        #{child.name}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">DOB</f:facet>
        #{child.dob}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

If I change the `FetchType` to `EAGER`, I don't get the exception but I want the data fetching to be lazy, i.e. only on demand.  What do I need to change to avoid this exception?

**May be related**

In the view, which does get successfully rendered when the `FetchType` is `EAGER`, I have a form to add a child for each parent and, once a child is added, I try to use `f:ajax` to refresh the children list table automatically:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Child" action="#{parentBean.addChild}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="childTbl"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

However, that refresh fails as the child table does not get updated with a new row when I add a child upon AJAX (which I do in order to avoid reloading the page), even though the corresponding DB transaction succeeds.  The newly added child is only visible in the table when I refresh the view in the browser by reloading the page.

However, please note that the `LazyInitializationException` occurs when I first try to load the page with a parent and their children when the `FetchType` is `LAZY`.  It is not directly related to the refresh failure, which happens when the `FetchType` is `EAGER`.  But I thought there might be some fundamental flaw in my code that, when fixed, will enable both a lazy initialization as well as the AJAX view refresh.

Comment: do you refresh your parent entity once you're done with the transaction?

Comment: yes, `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="childTbl"/>` should do that

Comment: You can see this answer , the same issue but with jsp page     [link] [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047835/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-while-using-collection-in-spring-jsp-page

Comment: This is because you are trying to refer to a lazily initialized collection here in this EL `#{parent.children}`. I assume the EL refers to `private List<Child> childList` being returned by `getChildren()` in the `Parent` entity. This has whatsoever nothing to do with JSF. Use a separate query to retrieve a list of children based on its parent row depending upon the functional requirements or project's structure/flow.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define FetchType.LAZY fetching for  childList column; take a look at FetchType.LAZY and FetchType.EAGER differences from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence) . If you want to get not null childList object, there are 2 options:

1. Change FetchType.LAZY  to FetchType.EAGER
2. When your Child object persistent call getChildren() inside @Transaction annotationed method.